# Invalid Label error in JSONP

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, cross-domain

my json url is :

http://app.websitename.in/getToken

above url return me following JSON :

```
 { token: "2cd3e37b-5d61-4070-96d5-3dfce0d0acd9%a00a5e34-b017-4899-8171-299781c48c72" }
```

**Edit**: Changed it to

```
 { "token": "2cd3e37b-5d61-4070-96d5-3dfce0d0acd9%a00a5e34-b017-4899-8171-299781c48c72" }
```

I am (still) getting Invalid Label error while calling following code

my code is :

```
 $.getJSON("http://app.websitename.in/getToken?callback=?", 
function(data) {
alert("success");
    alert("Symbol: " + data.token);
});
```

Please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my json url is :
>   http://app.websitename.in/getToken

No, it isn't (or, if it is, then its broken).

curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'app.websitename.in'

If we assume that you mean "example.com" when you say "websitename.in" (use the example domains for examples, that is what they are there for) then:

If it returns that data, in that form, then it is failing to wrap it in a callback, so it is JSON and not JSON-P. You need JSON-P to operate across domains.

Answer (score 7):

Property names **must** be in double quotes to be valid JSON, e.g.:

```
{ token: "2cd3e37b-5d61-4070-96d5-3dfce0d0acd9%a00a5e34-b017-4899-8171-299781c48c72" }
```

must be

```
{ "token": "2cd3e37b-5d61-4070-96d5-3dfce0d0acd9%a00a5e34-b017-4899-8171-299781c48c72" }
```

(Note that "token" is now in double quotes.)

Details on the [JSON site](http://json.org). [JSONlint](http://www.jsonlint.com/) is also helpful.

Some JSON parsers are lax and let you get away with not putting double quotes around property names (particularly ones that are really JavaScript parsers in disguise), but technically, it's required.

Comment: Doesn't doing cross-domain JSON-P treat the data as a JavaScript fragment (where this is valid) and not as JSON?

Comment: @David: You may well be right. And certainly if the URL is returning the raw data rather than a valid JSON-P response, yours is the correct answer.

Comment: @Tushar: As of your edit, it's now correct. If you're still having the problem, and based on your updated error message, I'm sure @David's right: You're really returning that text from the URL, which is just pure JSON, not a valid **JSON-P** response. JSON-P requires that you wrap your JSON in a call to a function, details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP

Comment: how can i return JSON-P instead of JSON ? ....please tell me the procedure. am using Java on server side

Comment: @Tushar: The link I just gave you has a complete example.

Comment: @T.J Crowder...i want to return my JSON string on perticular event not on body load

Comment: @Tushar: Who said anything about body load? Give the JSON-P article a thorough read, look at the examples, and you'll see. Your response should be something like `someFunctionName({token: "...."});` where you get the name of the function from the URL (it's the "callback" parameter).

Comment: @Tushar: Much as I appreciate your marking this the "correct" answer, based on the comments above, I think the right answer is the one from @David. :-) Best,